# Change the delete icon for material ui chip to a custom svg?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I would like to use a custom svg icon instead of the default delete icon for the material ui chip element. 
Is this possible or would it be a new feature request?

I was only able to change the color of the icon but not the icon itself...

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: how did you change the color of the material ui delete icon? I been trying to do this for too long right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import IconSVG from @materialui/icons/IconSVG

<Chip 
  label="delete me"
  deleteIcon={<IconSVG />}
  onDelete={this.deleteMethod}
/>
```

In the chip api of material ui there is a props : deleteIcon it allows to change the delete icon using onDelete